# Problem with -split functionality in Powershell

Tags: powershell

**Hello I am having some trouble while trying to loop over a colomn in a export csv table.**

```
$userproxy = $null
    foreach($proxy in $foundUser.proxyAddresses) {
       
        if($proxy.substring(0,4) -like "smtp" -or $proxy.substring(0,4) -like "SMTP") {
            $userproxy += $proxy + "-" 
        }        
    }
```

**this is the code used to export the user proxyAddresses which is then added to table. An exmaple of how the table is affected, this table is used to migrate a user from one domain to another. **

```
"Name","givenName","sn","sAMAccountName","mail","mailNickname","mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid","targetAddress","proxyAddresses"
"John Doe","John","Doe","B004796","jdoe@local.com","jdoe","7c8f6e36-7a21-254a-ae7b-85adb256a777","SMTP:jdoe@local.com","smtp:jdoe@local.grp-SMTP:jdoe@local.com-"
```

**your text**

**Then on the other DC, while trying to use the data from the csv file I tried to loop over each of the proxies**

```
$proxyToAdd = $userInfo.proxyAddresses -split "-"
         foreach($proxy in $proxyToAdd){
            Write-Host $item
            Set-ADUser $foundUser.sAMAccountName -add @{proxyAddresses = $proxy}
         }
```

**When launched it returns the following error.**

```
smtp:jdoe@local.grp
SMTP:jdoe@local.com

Set-ADUser : add
Au caractère D:\Scripts\Migration Eneria\Traitement_Migration.ps1:48 : 13
+             Set-ADUser $foundUser.sAMAccountName -add @{proxyAddresse ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (proteauclementt:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

**I dont really understand what the error is, I also tried the following**

```
$userInfo.proxyAddresses -split "-" | foreach{
            Write-Host $_
            Set-ADUser $foundUser.sAMAccountName -add @{proxyAddresses = $_}
         }
```

**That returned an error not valide type**

Comment: It's failing because of the trailing `-`, the last result from the `-split` operation will be an empty string. Do `$userInfo.proxyAddressess.Split('-', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead

Answer (score 2):

Let's try and apply your `-split` operation in isolation and see what *actually* happens here:

```
PS ~> $proxyAddresses = "smtp:jdoe@local.grp-SMTP:jdoe@local.com-"
PS ~> $proxyAddresses -split '-' |ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Got substring '$_'" }
Got substring 'smtp:jdoe@local.grp'
Got substring 'SMTP:jdoe@local.com'
Got substring ''
```

Aha! The trailing `-` means that the `-split` operation returns an array where the last item is just an *empty string* - this is probably what `Set-ADUser` is complaining about!

You can filter out the empty string:

```
$proxyToAdd = $userInfo.proxyAddresses -split "-" |Where-Object { $_ }
```

Or you can use [the `String.Split()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) instead, as it can be made to discard empty results:

```
$proxyToAdd = $userInfo.proxyAddresses.Split("-", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```